# Storing variables temporarily from MYSQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called members, i have a file i include in all of my pages which pulls up data from the members table using the stored session variables.

```
$getRecords = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?");
$getRecords->execute([ $_SESSION['logedin_id'] ]); 
$users_record = $getRecords->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
$getRecords = null;
$name = $users_record->name;
$email = $users_record->email;
$phone = $users_record->mobile;
$activatedStat = $users_record->a_status;
```

I need the  variables `$name, $email, $phone and $activatedStat` to be stored throughout the period of the users login without having to access the database everytime I load a page. 
Do I have to use sessions like `$_SESSION['name'] = $users_record->name;?` 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, sessions store the data on the server for the whole duration of users session.

Comment: And if the user updates his profile, how do i handle that?

Comment: Update the session values as well as database entries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: @dılosürücü That has nothing to do with PHP memory.

Comment: Use memcache or redis for store to memory